# how to detect files related to an app on a mac

Tags: macos, uninstallation

I am wondering how an application like appzapper can detect the files related to an application?

All ideas are welcome.

Thanks for your help,

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By looking into the standard locations that usually are used by applications to store preferences (like `Library/Preferences`/ , `Library/Caches`, etc., both in your home directory `~/` and under `/` ) I couldn´t find any file or folder that isn´t using either the applications name (eg. `~/Library/Application Support/Firefox`) or it´s bundle identifier (eg. `~/Library/Preferences/org.mozilla.firefox.plist`) in its name; so I guess they´re just using that.

In the case of AppZapper you can go ahead and try for any (not currently running) Application to rename the `~/Library/Application Support/AppName` folder for example to `~/Library/Application Support/111AppName` - AppZapper doesn´t find it anymore. If you change it to  `~/Library/Application Support/AppName111` it shows up as a related file.

Out of this you can conclude that there isn´t any magical linkage between a folder full of preferences and it´s associated application that AppZapper is reading out, it´s merely checking for folders starting with the Application´s Name.

Comment: Thanks for this detailled answer!